# Ultimate DRY model rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I'm refactoring my model rspecs as to be "as DRY" as possible, leading to something like

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Model do
  subject { build(:model) }

  it { should be_valid }

  it { should validate_presence_of(:description) }
  it { should ensure_length_of(:description).is_at_least(3).is_at_most(255) }

  it { should validate_presence_of(:position) }
  it { should validate_numericality_of(:position).is_greater_than_or_equal_to(1) }  
end
```

Now, every file starts with

```
  subject { build(:model) }

  it { should be_valid }
```

so, you guess it, I would like to get rid of these two lines as well...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't refactor tests to be "as DRY as possible", because they also need more readability. Readability trumps DRY, so just as DRY code can be more readable, DRY tests often aren't.

Comment: ^-- What @Danny Van Hoof said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `it { should be_valid }` test seems to be testing only your factory. It's not really important to the function of the Model. Consider moving these tests to a single `factories_spec` test if you'd like to test them. See: https://github.com/thoughtbot/suspenders/blob/master/templates/factories_spec.rb

The matchers you are using in your example don't really require a model built with FactoryGirl. They will work fine with the implicit, default subject (Model.new). When that's not the case, I'd suggest defining as much of the state of your test as possible inside the test -- that is, inside the `it` blocks. If that results in some duplication, so be it. Particularly costly duplication can be extracted to method calls, which are preferable to `subject`, `let` and `before` because there's no magic to them. As a developer coming back to the project in 6 months, looking at spec on line 75, you'll know exactly what the setup is.

See: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/lets-not

Comment: I like the idea of the separate factory tester. Your second remark however leads to "mixed" error messages, as the validation errors of other attributes start popping in. Using a factory seems to prevent this...

Comment: It shouldn't. Those matchers look for the presence of the *correct* error message on the *correct* attribute.

Comment: As you should. But the matchers only assert against the error you tell it to look for. https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/validate_presence_of_matcher.rb#L29

Comment: The ensure_length_of matcher gives me an error like 'Expected errors to include "is too short (minimum 3 characters)" when description is set to "xx", got errors: ["description is too short (minimum 10 characters) (\"xx\")", "position must be greater than or equal to 1 (0)"].' There is nothing wrong with position though, only with description... Cause of the "additional error" on position is purely that a "new" object indeed causes the position validation to be violated as well. That's why I would suggest to use an in-between factory. Alternative would be that the matcher excludes this error

Comment: With an in-between factory, the error becomes "Expected errors to include "is too short (minimum 3 characters)" when description is set to "xx", got errors: ["description is too short (minimum 10 characters) (\"xx\")"], which is much more "normal" and instructive. Just my 2 cents

Comment: Are you misunderstanding the include matcher output? It's saying it expected to see <foo> in the array but the entire array was <bar>. It's not doing an equality check on the array, it's doing an include check. The output is saying, "I expected to see this error but I don't see it. Here are all the errors I do see, though."

Comment: I understand it is doing this, but I don't understand it can't pick out the error messages corresponding to the attribute being tested, exactly like the errors in a view are assigned to the attributes on the screen. This would make it, my point of view, more "informational". A bit like the wood and the trees: the more you can limit the amount of info, the more focused it becomes. That's why I'm using the FactoryGirl object. It makes all the "bullshit" go away, limiting the output to the essential

Answer (score 2):

You can use rspec [shared examples](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples):

```
shared_examples "a model" do
  subject { build described_class }
  it { should be_valid }
end

describe Foo do
  it_behaves_like "a model"
end

describe Bar do
  it_behaves_like "a model"
end
```

Comment: I like this idea too, but it seems to execute in a nested context, so that the subject is not available to the other examples. By modifying it to include_examples "it should behave like a model" this can be fixed

Comment: @DannyVanHoof `subject` defined out of band of the test but in the same file is bad enough. I'd urge you not to define `subject` in an entirely different file. The fact that shared example has a nested context is a *good* thing.

Comment: I understand and agree